# Corona - In-App Purchase Consumable Product Error ( You have already purchased.... )

Tags: ios6, in-app-purchase, coronasdk

I'm trying to make an update to my application. Before iOS6 everything was fine. But now, I face with this problem:

1 . I buy a product. ( Sandbox mode, consumable product )
2 . Everything works correctly
3 . Then I try to buy the same product again. It gives me this massage :

```
 "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded. Tap OK to download it now. [Environment : Sandbox]"
```

After that, if I click to ok and tap to buy it, store returns some other transactions as purchased.

Note that, I use store.finishtransaction() function after all pruchases.
I hope someone knows how to deal with this.

Dogancan

Comment: Now I also have this error : 
When I open the app, store.init() function is called and I recieve some reciepts from app store. They all are purchased products

Comment: After upgrading the devices to iOS 6.1.3 (not sure that's the cause) and Xcode to the latest - that is yesterday, my app (not Corona, own engine, sandboxed) started to receive multiple transactions from the store (both redeems and new purchases). Luckily we only have one-time purchases, so we can ignore multiple store responses. This is happening on a code that was developed, tested, working in another live app and not modified since. I suspect it's a bug (hopefully only in) the sandboxed AppStore. Also, the redeem started to work in several steps (not all redeems at once).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps.

1) go to settings -> iTunes apps and sign out of your account.

2) double push home button and close all open apps.

3) do a hard reset- hold power button on top and home button down at same time till apple icon 
appears and let it reboot.

4) Go back in to settings and sign into your iTunes account again and try in-App purchase again.